# Projection functions are homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

Let $p_1: X \times Y \rightarrow X$ be a projection. Then $p_1$ is and open map,so $\forall U \subset X \times Y$ open, $p_1(U) \subset X$ open (which is making $p_1 ^{-1}: X \rightarrow X \times Y$ continuous), and $p_1$ itself is a continuous function. Is this correct?

Comment: The projection is indeed an open and continuous map, but that doesn't prove it's a homeomorphism.

Comment: p_1 is not iniective so you can't invert it and can't be one homeomorphism. Think to the unit interval [0,1] and the unit square [0,1]x[0,1] and findout why they are not "the same" space, topologically speaking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The projection $p_1$ is an open and continuous map, indeed. But $(p_1)^{-1}$ is not a function in general, as $p_1$ is not 1-1.

Answer (score 1):

To view how this reflects "in nature", take $I=[0,1]$ the unit interval and $I^2=I×I$. If the projection to o one component $p$ was a homeomorphism, then $I\setminus \{0.5 \}$ that is not a conncted space would be isomorphic to $I^2\setminus \{ \text{one point}\}$ that is connected independently on the point that you remove. Keep in mind this kind of  reasoning, that is useful on a lot of cases and exercises.